Noise Fluctuation with MAX40660
I am currently implementing MAX40660 as a high speed TIA amplifier. In the process of testing the basic functionality of the circuit, I have implemented a pcb design similar to the evaluation kit. When I try to quantify and confirm the output voltage noise spectral density, I am seeing a strange phenonmenon describe as following:

Photodiode unilluminated was connected to the input of the TIA chip with proper bias. All of the constant voltage port have been checked to have proper stable voltage with an oscilloscope probe tip at each point.

When using the ESA to measure the AC output port, the noise fluctuation in the order of 20dB, randomly.

When using the oscilloscope for the AC output port, rms of the output can be seen to have a combination of random repeating spikes, thicker lines (more noise signal), thinner lines (less noise signal) at random intervals (auto trigger can be causing the randomness). The integrated noise spectrum is not stable.

When using the ESA for measuring the noise spectral density with a smaller span, it poses the following characteristics in the figure, with the spikes slowly moving to the right. This seems to indicate the noise fluctuation is temporal of nature instead of frequency-dependent. As the scan is 30ms, it seems to be repeating with approximately ms-level periodicity.



Could you be able to identify what is wrong with the circuit? or How should I be debugging this board?
Thanks in advance!
